# Add bones to an armature deformed in pose position

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I have a simple pistol model with one root bone.

[image]

It has a Childof constraint to the hand-bone of a character.

Now I want to add a new bones to the Pistol armature, so I go to edit mode, which shows the rest position then, add a bone there and define the root as parent of the new bone.

[image]

When I go back to pose psotion then and pose mode, the new bone is rotated like this:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it or what's the problem?

Thx!

Comment: it looks like your parent bone has a constraint, delete it, but are you sure you don't want to do the opposite, I mean make the root bone the parent of the new bone?

Comment: @moonboots Sorry, description was wrong. Yes, the root will be the parent of the new bone. And yes, the root bone of the pistol has a constraint to the hand of the character (child of), but I need it.

Edit: Ah I see, the new bone was a copy of the parent and the constraint was copied. I removed the constraint from the new bone, now it works... thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your new bone is green in *Pose* mode, it means it has a constraint, just delete this constraint.